# How to shorten offset code VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a project tracker for work and need help shortening the code. Each manufacture has their own sheet. I have a Userform that the project manager enters the data in. Each of the manufacture sheets are identical and so are the offsets linked to the userform.

Please see the code below. I am new to coding and could use some help.

```
'A&R 5X9N
If Me.CB7.Value = "A&R" And Me.CB23.Value = "5x9N" Then
rowcount = Worksheets("A&R").Range("c3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("A&R").Range("c1")

'PROJECT
.Offset(rowcount, 0) = Me.CB1.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 1) = Me.TB2.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 2) = Me.TB3.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 3) = Me.CB4.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 4) = Me.CB7.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 5) = Me.TB1.Value
'FINISH DATES
.Offset(rowcount, 7) = Me.TB23.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 8) = Me.TB24.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 9) = Me.TB25.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 10) = Me.TB26.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 11) = Me.TB27.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 12) = Me.TB28.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 13) = Me.TB29.Value
'PRODUCTION
.Offset(rowcount, 14) = Me.TB8.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 15) = Me.TB9.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 16) = Me.TB10.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 17) = Me.TB11.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 18) = Me.TB12.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 19) = Me.TB13.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 20) = Me.TB14.Value
'ASSETS
.Offset(rowcount, 21) = Me.TB16.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 22) = Me.TB17.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 23) = Me.TB18.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 24) = Me.TB19.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 25) = Me.TB20.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 26) = Me.TB21.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 27) = Me.TB22.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 28) = Me.CB23.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 29) = Me.CB24.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 30) = Me.CB25.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 31) = Me.CB26.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 32) = Me.CB27.Value

End With
End If

'A&R 5X10N
If Me.CB7.Value = "A&R" And Me.CB23.Value = "5x10N" Then
rowcount = Worksheets("A&R").Range("AM3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("A&R").Range("AM1")

'PROJECT
.Offset(rowcount, 0) = Me.CB1.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 1) = Me.TB2.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 2) = Me.TB3.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 3) = Me.CB4.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 4) = Me.CB7.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 5) = Me.TB1.Value
'FINISH DATES
.Offset(rowcount, 7) = Me.TB23.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 8) = Me.TB24.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 9) = Me.TB25.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 10) = Me.TB26.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 11) = Me.TB27.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 12) = Me.TB28.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 13) = Me.TB29.Value
'PRODUCTION
.Offset(rowcount, 14) = Me.TB8.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 15) = Me.TB9.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 16) = Me.TB10.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 17) = Me.TB11.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 18) = Me.TB12.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 19) = Me.TB13.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 20) = Me.TB14.Value
'ASSETS
.Offset(rowcount, 21) = Me.TB16.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 22) = Me.TB17.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 23) = Me.TB18.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 24) = Me.TB19.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 25) = Me.TB20.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 26) = Me.TB21.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 27) = Me.TB22.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 28) = Me.CB23.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 29) = Me.CB24.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 30) = Me.CB25.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 31) = Me.CB26.Value
.Offset(rowcount, 32) = Me.CB27.Value

End With
End If
```

Comment: So you want to make it more efficient?

Comment: Optimize by using [Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264224.aspx) and [loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_for_loop.htm). This won't solve all of your issues, but it should help you write your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going to 2 subs. One that drives the boat (ProcessRecord) and one that does the grunt work (WriteRecord). This would at least help avoid repeating all of those Offsets.

```
Private Sub ProcessRecord()
    If Me.CB7.Value = "A&R" And Me.CB23.Value = "5x9N" Then WriteRecord "A&R", "C3"
    If Me.CB7.Value = "A&R" And Me.CB23.Value = "5x10N" Then WriteRecord "A&R", "AM1"
End Sub

Private Sub WriteRecord(wks As String, rng As String)
    Dim rowcount As Long
    rowcount = Worksheets(wks).Range(rng).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets(wks).Range(rng)
        'PROJECT
        .Offset(rowcount, 0) = Me.CB1.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 1) = Me.TB2.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 2) = Me.TB3.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 3) = Me.CB4.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 4) = Me.CB7.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 5) = Me.TB1.Value
        'FINISH DATES
        .Offset(rowcount, 7) = Me.TB23.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 8) = Me.TB24.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 9) = Me.TB25.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 10) = Me.TB26.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 11) = Me.TB27.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 12) = Me.TB28.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 13) = Me.TB29.Value
        'PRODUCTION
        .Offset(rowcount, 14) = Me.TB8.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 15) = Me.TB9.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 16) = Me.TB10.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 17) = Me.TB11.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 18) = Me.TB12.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 19) = Me.TB13.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 20) = Me.TB14.Value
        'ASSETS
        .Offset(rowcount, 21) = Me.TB16.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 22) = Me.TB17.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 23) = Me.TB18.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 24) = Me.TB19.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 25) = Me.TB20.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 26) = Me.TB21.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 27) = Me.TB22.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 28) = Me.CB23.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 29) = Me.CB24.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 30) = Me.CB25.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 31) = Me.CB26.Value
        .Offset(rowcount, 32) = Me.CB27.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can shorten your code. This is a piece from your code:

```
    .Offset(rowcount, 7) = Me.TB23.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 8) = Me.TB24.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 9) = Me.TB25.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 10) = Me.TB26.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 11) = Me.TB27.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 12) = Me.TB28.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 13) = Me.TB29.Value
    'PRODUCTION
    .Offset(rowcount, 14) = Me.TB8.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 15) = Me.TB9.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 16) = Me.TB10.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 17) = Me.TB11.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 18) = Me.TB12.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 19) = Me.TB13.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 20) = Me.TB14.Value
    'ASSETS
    .Offset(rowcount, 21) = Me.TB16.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 22) = Me.TB17.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 23) = Me.TB18.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 24) = Me.TB19.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 25) = Me.TB20.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 26) = Me.TB21.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 27) = Me.TB22.Value
```

Since all values are in a numeric order and all start with TB, you can use a loop to shorten the code:

```
For x = 7 To 27

    If x = 7 Then
        t = 23
    ElseIf x = 14 Then
        t = 8
    ElseIf x = 21 Then
        t = 16
    End If

    .Offset(rowcount, x) = Me.Controls("TB" & t).Value
    t = t + 1

Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea:

```
project = Array(CB1.value, TB2.value, TB3.value, CB4.value, CB7.value, TB1.value)
.Offset(rowcount, 0).resize(1, Ubound(project)-1).Value = project

finishDates= Array(TB23.value, TB24.value, TB25.value, TB26.value, TB27.value, TB28.value, TB29.Value)
.Offset(rowcount, 7).resize(1, Ubound(finishDates)-1).Value = finishDates
```

etc etc...

p.s. if you controls were numbered sequentially you could write a loop exploiting the sequencing of their names, but that is not your case (not always AFAICS) and moreover it is not recommended to count on that, because  it will be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

you could refactor your code as follows:

```
    If Me.CB7.Value = "A&R" Then 'A&R
        With Worksheets("A&R")
            Select Case Me.CB23.Value
                Case "5x9N" '5X9N
                    Write_em .Range("C1"), .Range("C3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

                Case "5x10N" '5X1N
                    Write_em .Range("AM1"), .Range("AM3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
            End Select
        End With
    End If
```

which exploits the following `Write_em()` sub:

```
Sub Write_em(rng As Range, RowCount As Long)
    With rng
        'PROJECT
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = Me.CB1.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = Me.TB2.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 2) = Me.TB3.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 3) = Me.CB4.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Me.CB7.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 5) = Me.TB1.Value
        'FINISH DATES
        .Offset(RowCount, 7) = Me.TB23.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 8) = Me.TB24.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 9) = Me.TB25.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 10) = Me.TB26.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 11) = Me.TB27.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 12) = Me.TB28.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 13) = Me.TB29.Value
        'PRODUCTION
        .Offset(RowCount, 14) = Me.TB8.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 15) = Me.TB9.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 16) = Me.TB10.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 17) = Me.TB11.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 18) = Me.TB12.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 19) = Me.TB13.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 20) = Me.TB14.Value
        'ASSETS
        .Offset(RowCount, 21) = Me.TB16.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 22) = Me.TB17.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 23) = Me.TB18.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 24) = Me.TB19.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 25) = Me.TB20.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 26) = Me.TB21.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 27) = Me.TB22.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 28) = Me.CB23.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 29) = Me.CB24.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 30) = Me.CB25.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 31) = Me.CB26.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 32) = Me.CB27.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Moreover, for the sake of shortening code only, you could refactor this latter as follows:

```
Sub Write_em(rng As Range, RowCount As Long)
    With rng
        'PROJECT
        .Offset(RowCount, 0).Resize(, 6).Value = Array(Me.CB1.Value, Me.TB2.Value, Me.TB3.Value, Me.CB4.Value, Me.CB7.Value, Me.TB1.Value)
        'FINISH DATES
        WriteTBs .Offset(RowCount, 7), 23, 29
        'PRODUCTION
        WriteTBs .Offset(RowCount, 14), 8, 14
        'ASSETS
        WriteTBs .Offset(RowCount, 21), 16 27
    End With
End Sub

Sub WriteTBs(rng As Range, iniTB As Integer, endTB As Integer)
    Dim iTb As Integer, colOffset As Integer

    With rng
        For iTb = iniTB To endTB
            .Offset(, colOffset) = Me.Controls("TB" & iTb).Value
            colOffset = colOffset + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```